# Using HTTP OPTIONS to retrieve information about REST resources

Tags: java, http, rest, restlet

This problem relates to the Restlet framework and Java

When a client wants to discover the resources available on a server - they must send an HTTP request with OPTIONS as the request type.  This is fine I guess for non human readable clients - i.e. in code rather than a browser.

The problem I see here is - browsers (human readable) using GET, will NOT be able to quickly discover the resources available to them and find out some extra help documentation etc - because they do not use OPTIONS as a request type.

Is there a way to make a browser send an OPTIONS/GET request so the server can fire back formatted XML to the client (as this is what happens in Restlet - i.e. the server response is to send all information back as XML), and display this in the browser?
Or have I got my thinking all wrong - i.e. the point of OPTIONS is that is meant to be used inside a client's code and not meant to be read via a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`TunnelService`](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/1.1/api/org/restlet/service/TunnelService.html) (which by default is already enabled) and simply add the `method=OPTIONS` query parameter to your URL.

(The [Restlet FAQ Q19](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/1.1/faq#19) is a similar question.)

Comment: Do you have any idea how you implement this - not much to go by just from the API docs.  Cheers.

Comment: It is enabled by default, created, and set up with default configuration in the Application(Context) constructor.

Comment: ok - I had some code that was meddling with TunnelService - so removed that and just from the browser - entered method=OPTIONS as you said and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think OPTIONS is not designed to be 'user-visible'.

How would you dispatch an OPTIONS request from the browser ? (note that the form element only [allows](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.1) GET and POST).

You could send it using [XmlHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) and then get back XML in your Javascript callback and render it appropriately. But I'm not convinced this is something that your user should really know about!